# Ordering by more than one field?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

i have this query

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT u.id,u.email,u.verified,u.verified_on,u.created_on,ca.html AS age,cg.html AS gender,cs.html AS state
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN combo ca ON ca.combo_group='age' AND ca.value =u.age
LEFT JOIN combo cg ON cg.combo_group='gender' AND cg.value =u.gender
LEFT JOIN combo cs ON cs.combo_group='state' AND cs.value =u.state ORDER BY created_on DESC) users ORDER BY email ASC;
```

I am using sub query because i want sort created_on DESC and email ASC

does this affect performance if i use sub query.

Comment: Not just affects performance: it won't give the expected result either.

Comment: why it will give unexpected?

Comment: Because it'll end up sorted by email, ignoring the order by created_on entirely.

Comment: ok thanks , i checked it's giving unexpected result

Comment: User has cross-posted this to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/37025/26613

Comment: No idea what that site is there for.

Comment: @DavidAldridge, it's there for code that works but looks like spaghetti.  check out the [About Page](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) that might help you understand why it is there as well.

Comment: @DavidAldridge more like, you've written code that does what you want it to be doing, and then you look at it and wonder, **"does this code make my ass look fat?"** - CR is taking your code into *peer review*, which is great to ensure that you're not the only mortal that can stand working with your code base.

Comment: Well, you see just those sort of "can this be improved on?" questions on SE and I don't recall seeing one closed as off-topic. On CR you see "does my code work?" and "how do I ...?" as well. Might as well bundle it all into SE -- the overlap in actual usage between the two is bigger than the intended distinction. IMHO.

Comment: @DavidAldridge that's been discussed before, take a look: [Fold Code Review back into Stack Overflow](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/917/23788). How about folding Programmers and CodeGolf into SO as well then? A whole community could be replaced with a simple tag, right? Wrong. You don't review a piece of working code like you answer a SO question (i.e. in 15 seconds), [tag:code-review] questions would just get drowned and forgotten in a sea of much easier-to-earn-rep-for questions. The CR community is far more relaxed (and welcoming!), there's no *fastest gun* in that west.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you order by two fields?

```
SELECT 
     u.id
    ,u.email
    ,u.verified
    ,u.verified_on
    ,u.created_on
    ,ca.html AS age
    ,cg.html AS gender
    ,cs.html AS state
FROM users u
    LEFT JOIN combo ca ON ca.combo_group='age' AND ca.value =u.age
    LEFT JOIN combo cg ON cg.combo_group='gender' AND cg.value =u.gender
    LEFT JOIN combo cs ON cs.combo_group='state' AND cs.value =u.state 
ORDER BY created_on DESC, email ASC
```

Comment: oh is this possible ? i was not knowing

Comment: Yes, you can order by several fields

Comment: ... and by expressions, and often by the results of a subquery.